# Editing xml Document using SSIS script task

Tags: c#, xml, ssis

My XML looks like below:

[image]

I would like to edit some more file related info above the `<customer>` tag. Please see below the format which I require:

[image]

Kindly help me to sort it out using SSIS script task.

Comment: Do you want it done in C# or SSIS script task?

Comment: is SSIS script task.using C#

Comment: So it is a SSIS configuration file that you want to modify in C#.  I can create the xml file using XML Linq Net Library.